# Converting a dataframe from inside a pandas Dataframe - Alice Blue API

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie alert, please bear

the data i have right now after running the line of code below is

Input-

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol)
```

Output-

```
    Index                                       NSE
1018GS2026 GS   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6833, symbol='1018GS2026 GS', name='GOI LOAN 10.18% 
                2026', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
1025GS2021 GS   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6819, symbol='1025GS2021 GS', name='GOI LOAN 10.25% 
                2021', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
116GS2020 GS    Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=6814, symbol='116GS2020 GS', name='GOI LOAN 11.60% 
                2020', expiry=None, lot_size='1')
182D010721 TB   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1776, symbol='182D010721 TB', name='GOI TBILL 182D- 
                01/07/21', expiry=None, lot_size='100')
182D020921 TB   Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=2593, symbol='182D020921 TB', name='GOI TBILL 182D- 
                02/09/21', expiry=None, lot_size='100')
```

I want a dataframe like this from inside the above dataframe

```
    Index      Exchange  token     symbol             name            expiry  lot_size 
1018GS2026 GS    NSE     6833   1018GS2026 GS  GOI LOAN 10.18% 2026    None      1
1025GS2021 GS    NSE     6819   1025GS2021 GS  GOI LOAN 10.25% 2021    None      1
116GS2020 GS     NSE     6814   116GS2020 GS   GOI LOAN 11.60% 2020    None      1
182D010721 TB    NSE     1776   182D010721 TB  GOI TBILL 182D-01/07/21 None     100
182D020921 TB    NSE     2593   182D020921 TB  GOI TBILL 182D-02/09/21 None     100
```

Any suggestions guys?, what should i do?

Comment: What is `alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol`?  Is it a dictionary?  What you'll want to do is run through that list and convert it to a format that pandas can recognize.

Comment: My first idea would be to split your rows by "=" and delimiter ",". Then you could create a new dataframe with according headers and every second column of your old dataframe. That should be your expected result

Comment: @TimRoberts  yes it is a dict , can you elaborate further, i am having trouble understanding , i am a newbie

Comment: Is this fixed length data? I meant the Input file. Can you please share the input data as is.

Comment: @MattisSeehaus Hi bro, can you elaborate more, I am a total noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol)
df = pd.json_normalize([x._asdict() for x in df['NSE']]).set_index(df.index)
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

**IF** the master_contract has the index as its key, and an `Instrument` object as its value, then it should be easy to convert this.

```
rows = []

for val in alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol.values():
    row.append( [val.exchange, val.token, val.symbol, val.name,
                val.expiry, val.lot_size] )

df = pd.DataFrame( rows,
    index=alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol.keys(),
    columns=['exchange', 'token', 'symbol', 'name', 'expiry', 'lot_size']
)
```

**Edit:**
If the AliceBlue thing is really an OrderedDict of OrderedDicts, then it is even easier:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( 
    alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol.values(),
    index=alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol.keys()
)
```

Comment: Hi , i tried running it and got this error : AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'exchange'

Comment: Hi tim, so i put alice._AliceBlue__master_contracts_by_symbol inside a variable and i can see the value as OrderedDict object of collections module

Comment: and when i print it this is the format - {[('ZYLOG', Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=14879, symbol='ZYLOG',name='ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD.', expiry=None, lot_size=None))])}

Comment: Ah, if it's an OrderedDict, then it's even easier.  I'll modify the answer.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Prakul/Downloads/Screenshot%20(66).webp

Comment: i hope you can access the above screenshot, i am not getting the wanted result but something like in the above image, how can i have the desired format that i have mentioned in the question